# How to pass a uniform to a shader and what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to learn Javascript in WebGL, been trying to scour the internet and read up on it and learning how to use it but I just can't seem to realize what I'm doing wrong,

```js
   var canvas;
   var gl;
   var points = [];

   var numCirclePoints = 30;
   var radius = 0.5;

   function init() {
     dostuff();
     setInterval(dostuff, 1000);
   }

   function dostuff() {


     points = [];
     var x = Math.random();
     var y = Math.random();
     var xLocation;
     var yLocation;
     var center = vec2(x, y);
     // End of shenanigans

     canvas = document.getElementById("gl-canvas");
     gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL(canvas);
     if (!gl) {
       alert("WebGL isn't available");
     }

     gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
     gl.clearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

     //
     //  Load shaders and initialize attribute buffers
     //
     var program = initShaders(gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader");
     gl.useProgram(program);

     //console.log(center);

     points.push(center);
     createCirclePoints(center, radius, numCirclePoints);

     var vBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
     gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer);
     gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(points), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

     var vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "vPosition");
     gl.vertexAttribPointer(vPosition, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
     gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vPosition);
     xLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "x");
     yLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "y");
     render();
   }

   window.onload = init;


    // Create the points of the circle
   function createCirclePoints(cent, rad, k) {
     var dAngle = 2 * Math.PI / k;
     for (i = k; i >= 0; i--) {
       a = i * dAngle;

       var p = vec2(rad * Math.sin(a) + cent[0], rad * Math.cos(a) + cent[1]);
       points.push(p);
     }
   }

   function render() {
     gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
     gl.uniform1f(xLocation, x);
     gl.uniform1f(yLocation, y);
     // Draw circle using Triangle Fan
     gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, numCirclePoints + 2);

     window.requestAnimFrame(render);
   }

   Here 's the HTML I suspect my lack of knowledge in this shines there.

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252"><script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
    
    attribute vec4 vPosition;
    uniform float x;
    uniform float y;
    
    void
    main()
    {
        gl_Position = vPosition;
        gl_Position.x += x;
        gl_Position.y += y;
    
    }
    </script>
    
    <script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
    
    precision mediump float;
    
    void
    main()
    
    {
        gl_FragColor = vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
    }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="webgl-utils.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="initShaders.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="MV.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="dop.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="gl-canvas" width="512" height="512">&gt; Oops ... your browser doesn't support the HTML5 canvas element
  </canvas>


</body>

</html>
```

So yeah,the only thing I want to do is change the x variable into a uniform variable, however I can't! And I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: I don't understand.  `x` already is a uniform in your shader.  Is the value not affecting anything?  Maybe try something more deliberate like changing the color you output.  Does that work?

Comment: Ah! My problem is that I have a program which I wrote, which moved a circle around the canvas by calling upon an random function and then just moving the center around.
However, when I make the variable uniform, nothing happens.

Comment: So I feel like making the variable random, somehow ruined it. 
But I don't know how. Or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Where are `rndLocX` and `rndX` even declared?

Comment: It was my bad! rndX is ultimately supposed to be x and rndLoc is suppose to be xLocation and yLocation

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the location of the uniform in the shader program here in `dostuff`:

```
dostuff(){
    var xLocation;
    ...
    xLocation = gl.getUniformLocation( program, "x");
    ...
}
```

Then you are trying to use it in `render`:

```
function render() {
    ...
    gl.uniform1f(rndLocX, rndX);
    ...
}
```

The first problem is that you don't have scope access to `xLocation` in `render` because it was declared in `dostuff`.  The quick fix is to move the scope up.  Declare `xLocation` next to where you declare `numCirclePoints`.

The second problem that I think is happening is that you are using `uniform1f` incorrectly.  The signature is:

```
uniform1f(the_uniform_location, the_uniform_value);
```

So if you scope right, the basic flow would be:

```
var xLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "x");
var myRandX = Math.random() * (5);
gl.uniform1f(xLocation, myRandX);
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for the sweet replies, I was messing about with my code that's why it was kinda weird. >.< 
However! I did apply the fixes you suggested, however it had no effect on the program as it didn't display my red ball.
Nor any motion in the browser.